# How to call onDraw periodically?

Tags: android

I use ScrollView class in my application. I draw some data on canvas from the compass, these data are periodically updated by user's interaction.

How can I periodically call onDraw method without user's touch on the display? Can I periodically refresh content of the canvas without other thread and calling `view.postInvalidate()`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use another thread to do this?

Comment: I think that there is other way. If there isn't another way, I use thread...

Comment: The only way that I can see this happening is with a thread, the answer by DeeV below is what you should do. The Handler will allow you to make a call from your own thread to the UI thread.

Comment: thanks, I applied DeeV answer on it and it is fixed.

Comment: I just noticed this.  The Handler runs on the UI thread.  It's not its own thread like may be inferred here.

Answer (score 9):

The `Handler` class is very handy for things like this.

```
Handler viewHandler = new Handler();
Runnable updateView = new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
     globalView.invalidate();
     viewHandler.postDelayed(updateView, MILLISECONDS_TILL_UPDATE);
  }
};
```

Call `viewHandler.post(updateView);` anywhere in the UI thread and it will infinitely call that `Runnable` every x number of milliseconds specified in `MILLISECONDS_TILL_UPDATE`.  Call `viewHandler.removeCallbacks(updateView);` to end it or use a boolean flag to prevent another post.